# Importing pymongo on OpenShift

Tags: python, mongodb, openshift, pymongo

My OpenShift application, which is written in Python with a MongoDB database, is failing to import pymongo. My logs say

```
import pymongo
[Fri Jun 05 12:11:01 2015] [error] [client 127.10.149.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/55706c785973ca947100005a/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
[Fri Jun 05 12:11:01 2015] [error] [client 127.10.149.1]     from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
[Fri Jun 05 12:11:01 2015] [error] [client 127.10.149.1]   File "/var/lib/openshift/55706c785973ca947100005a/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 28, in <module>
[Fri Jun 05 12:11:01 2015] [error] [client 127.10.149.1]     from pymongo import (common,
[Fri Jun 05 12:11:01 2015] [error] [client 127.10.149.1] ImportError: cannot import name common
```

I can't find any mention of "common" in the pymongo documentation. Any idea what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: How did you install pymongo? What version do you have installed? It's trying to import https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/common.py

Comment: I installed pymongo by putting pymongo in my requirements.txt file. I assume it's the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It was an installation problem.

To fix it, I logged in using ssh, uninstalled pymongo and bson, made sure bson wasn't in requirements.txt, and pushed a change.

This did a clean install of pymongo.